# Force to download dependencies from repository but only for particular package

Tags: gradle

I am looking for a way to force to download only dependencies from particular package in Gradle (which comes from my company only and changing very often) instead of redownloading everything.

I know how to redownload everything by executing

```
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
```

or by

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

but is there any option to limits dependencies to download? All of them have the same prefix com.company.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can not control which dependency to refresh with `--refresh-dependencies`, it's not designed for that.

You will need specify a [rich version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html) for the changing dependencies. Then configure Gradle's caching of dynamic/rich versions to your liking:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.company:my-library:latest.release")
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, "seconds"
}
```